# node.js: Isn't this code vulnerable to directory traversal?

Tags: node.js

Can someone explain me why this code is not vulnerable?

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) { 
    var filePath = false;
    if (request.url == '/') { 
        filePath = 'public/index.html'; 
    } else { 
        console.log(request.url); 
        filePath = 'public' + request.url; 
    }

    var absPath = './' + filePath; 
    serveStatic(response, cache, absPath); 
});
```

isn't this vulnerable to directory traversal ? I read it in a book, Node.js in action.

Comment: Look at the default options for `serveStatic()` in [the doc here](https://ewiggin.gitbooks.io/expressjs-middleware/content/serve-static.html) and see if that answers your question.  If you're using a different `serveStatic()`, then please include a link to that documentation.  And, next time, please format your code to be readable.  I fixed it for you this time.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, the link you posted is for express, but i'm following an example from node.js in action in which i don't use any framework yet, i guess what you meant was that i should check the portion about dotfiles am i right? where doc talks about the treatment for paths with dots? the code above, is it vulnerable to directory traversal attacks? i tried curl and lets me get server js files, how could i fix it, i thought node would take charge about that or should i go directly with express and just take this as an basic example of how node.js works?

Comment: `serveStatic()` is not a generic part of node.js so it has to be coming from some 3rd party library. We can't really tell you what it does without knowing what code it is. I posted a link to a module that can be used with or without express. You need to show us the code that goes with the `serveStatic()` you are using. Otherwise, we can't possibly help you because we don't know what it does or what dot protection is has built in (or not). The simplest way to prevent upwards traversal is to just disallow any dots at the beginning of a path segment. Just fail the request with a 404 if dots exist

Comment: node.js doesn't do any traversal protection by itself.  The basic web server you are using, lets you do anything you want.  If you want to prevent traversal, you either have to code it yourself or use prebuilt code that prevents it (like Express and express.static())` which would be my recommendation.

Comment: I am such a fool! Thank you, i just noticed that i am implementing my own version of serveStatic, i will take that as a commonly beginner mistake. My actual code is: http://pastebin.com/mAUWr640. So, since i am a paranoid programmer about security, i trying to set up this new technology in my company system, should i think about node as insecure or trust it but use express as framework? (i heard express had issues with directory traversal time ago but fix it), what do you say?  i already fix my code with "normalize" method, would i need to do this always or express has this and other fixes?

Comment: When possible, it's usually best to use security features that have already been built, tested and vetted by others as that experience and process is usually better than what you will implement your first time. Express has no generic vulnerabilites for traversal because it serves NO files by default. It only serves files you build routes for.  It has an option with `express.static()` to serve whole directories of files automatically and it comes with a built-in option that is turned on by default to prevent upward traversal. Find the right tools, understand them and configure them correctly.

Comment: Ok, i get it.
So the link you posted earlier was to import one of those modules you talk about?
In general, should i be worried about security with express? or should i feel secure and besides that try to find the right tools as you say ?

Comment: FYI, as best I know, `path.normalize()` does not prevent upward traversal.  It just acts on the `..` and `.` parts of a path to convert them to the final path.

Comment: Also, there's no reason to use `fs.exists()` in your `serveStatic()`.  Just do `fs.readFile()` and handle the error if it doesn't exist.

Comment: No, what i meant was that normalize take off the dots and the regular expression replacement takes off the slash.. is there anything else should i take into account?

Comment: so, would you say that this solution is correct?
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/123720/how-to-prevent-directory-traversal-when-joining-paths-in-node-js

Comment: That's not my preferred implementation.  I looked at what [the `express.static()` code does](https://github.com/pillarjs/send/blob/master/index.js#L520) and I like it a lot better.  It just splits the path into components and outright rejects any path that has any path component that starts with a `.`. It also has other regex tests too.  That seems more foolproof.  But, I'm not an expert on the topic.

Comment: Ok thank you for the research, i will opt to use express as soon as i finish read all about node basics and advanced.